# Clear form field after uploading an image to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying for days to make sure that after submitting a jpg to google drive, it cleans the forms fields and leaves it ready for the next insertion of the next record. It copies the file but does not reset the field. What I want is that as soon as he uploads the file, he resets the form field without reloading it waiting for the next one to be uploaded. This example I took from the internet and I'm trying to adapt it to my needs

HTML:

```html
    <html>
     <head>
       <base target="_top">
     </head>
     <body>       
     <form>
       <input type="file" name="file" id="arq" />
       <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="id"/>
     </form>

    <script>   
       var vCampoEncarregado = document.getElementById('arq');       

       document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
       e.preventDefault();  
  
       const vFileReader = new FileReader();

       vFileReader.onload = function(e) {
         const vValores = vFileReader.result.split(',');
         const vObj = {
           fileName: document.querySelector('input[id="arq"]').files[0].name,
           mimeType: document.querySelector('input[id="arq"]').files[0].type,
           data: vValores[1] 
         }
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().SubirImagemAntes(vObj);     
       }
vFileReader.readAsDataURL(document.querySelector('input[id="arq"]').files[0]);
    
    });
    vCampoEncarregado.value = '';
  
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

GS:

```js
    function doGet() {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
    }

    function SubirImagemAntes(data) {
      const myFile = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data.data),     data.mimeType,data.fileName);
      const Id = "ID";
      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Id);
      const fileAdded = folder.createFile(myFile);

      const resp = {
        'url': fileAdded.getUrl(),
        'name': data.fileName
      };

      return resp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reset the file input tag after the file was uploaded.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this case, your Google Apps Script is not modified. Your HTML side is modified as follows.

#### From:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().SubirImagemAntes(vObj);
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => {
  console.log(res);
  document.getElementById("arq").value = "";
}).SubirImagemAntes(vObj);
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- The whole modified script is as follows.

```js
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="arq" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="id"/>
  </form>

<script>
var vCampoEncarregado = document.getElementById('arq');
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const vFileReader = new FileReader();
  vFileReader.onload = function (e) {
    const vValores = vFileReader.result.split(',');
    const vObj = {
      fileName: document.querySelector('input[id="arq"]').files[0].name,
      mimeType: document.querySelector('input[id="arq"]').files[0].type,
      data: vValores[1]
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => {
      console.log(res);
      document.getElementById("arq").value = "";
    }).SubirImagemAntes(vObj);
  }
  vFileReader.readAsDataURL(document.querySelector('input[id="arq"]').files[0]);
});
vCampoEncarregado.value = '';
  
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Great!! That's right...

Comment: @Gutemberg Silveira Alves GTTJ Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.