# Upload 2 images in different fields in Aps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two inputs and each will receive an image. I'm trying to upload these images to Google Drive, but I can only upload the last one, I've already tried to create an auxiliary function to verify if the file has already been created before proceeding with the "FileExists" function, but without success

Part of the Code HTML:

```
var myArray = ['antes','depois'];
var vFileReader = new FileReader();
   
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   if (i === 1) google.script.run.FileExists(document.getElementById('a').value);
          
   vFileReader.onload = function(e) {
     const vValores = vFileReader.result.split(',');
     const vObj = {
     fileName: document.querySelector('input[id=' + myArray[i] + ']').files[0].name,
     mimeType: document.querySelector('input[id=' + myArray[i] + ']').files[0].type,
     data: vValores[1]
     }
            
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().SubirImagem(vObj);
   }
     vFileReader.readAsDataURL(document.querySelector('input[id=' + myArray[i] + ']').files[0]);              
}
```

Part of the Code GS:

```
function SubirImagem(data) {
  const myFile = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data.data), data.mimeType,data.fileName);

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Id);
  const fileAdded = folder.createFile(myFile);

  const resp = {
    'url': fileAdded.getUrl(),
    'name': data.fileName
  };

  return resp;
}
     
function FileExists(vArqNome) {
  const vArqs = DriveApp.getFolderById(Id).getFiles();                  

  voltar: while (vArqs.hasNext()) {
  var vArq = vArqs.next();

  if (vArq.getName() != vArqNome) continue voltar; 
    break;
  }
```

}

[image]

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide your whole script? By the way, what is `if (i === 1) google.script.run.FileExists(document.getElementById('a').value);`?

Comment: It serves to verify if the 1st file was created in the destination folder, if so, then it continues to upload the 2nd, but without success

Comment: With this condition I check if it is already on the second time, which is the 2nd image. As it starts at 0 so the 2nd image is 1

Comment: The document.getElementById('a').value part is the value of the input field, which in this case is the file name, that is, I try to check if it has already been created there in the destination folder

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Either in the browser console or in the project executions?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')
    at vFileReader.onload

Comment: I don't know what I did that, now, it's not uploading even the last image...

Comment: When changing line position var vFileReader = new FileReader(); outside the for I get the error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Comment: In the previous case, it only uploads the last image, disregarding the 1st

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script of your showing Javascript. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileReader` and `google.script.run` are run with the asynchronous process. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Unfortunately, I cannot see the whole script of HTML and Javascript from your question. So, in this modification, I modified your showing script. Please be careful about this.

```js
const myArray = ['antes', 'depois'];
const f = myArray.reduce((ar, id) => {
  const files = document.querySelector(`input[id="${id}"]`).files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    const file = files[0];
    ar.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const vFileReader = new FileReader();
      vFileReader.onload = function (e) {
        const vValores = vFileReader.result.split(',');
        const vObj = { fileName: file.name, mimeType: file.type, data: vValores[1] };
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).SubirImagem(vObj);
      }
      vFileReader.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));
      vFileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }));
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
if (f.length == 0) return;
Promise.all(f)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    ['antes', 'depois'].forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).value = "");
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

- When this modified script is run, the files are retrieved from 2 input tags of `['antes', 'depois']` and the files are uploaded to Google Drive using your function of `SubirImagem`.
- In your showing Google Apps Script, `Id` of `const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Id);` is not declared. Please be careful about this.
- This modified script supposes that `['antes', 'depois']` are the file input tags. Please be careful about this.
- And, from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76794633), when the upload of files is finished, the file input tags are reset.

#### Note:

- In this case, I thought that because the files are uploaded in order, `if (i === 1) google.script.run.FileExists(document.getElementById('a').value);` might not be required to be used.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Gutemberg Silveira Alves GTTJ Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.